Relationship Between Forward Starting Swap Rates and Same-Tenor Forward Rates
New to all this. I'm playing around with a very basic swap pricer (in Excel, whose only input is the swap rate curve), and I noticed that although the 2y2y forward rate $f_{2,4}=\left(\frac{DF_2}{DF_4}\right)^{\frac{1}{4-2}}-1$ and the 2y forward starting 2y swap rate $R_{2,4}=\frac{\sum_{i=3}^{4}DF_{i}f_{i-1,i}}{\sum_{i=3}^{4}DF_{i}}$ were quite similar, they were off by a bit. I figured it was a rounding matter, so I tried doing it again with $f_{1,3}$ and $R_{1,3}$ and it seemed to persist. Clearly, they don't seem to be the same. But why? I'm leaning towards the fact that the swap rate depends on $DF_3$ (I assume more generally on the segment between Year 2 and Year 4) but the forward rate doesn't. Is there a specific shape of the swap curve that would make $f_{2,4}-R_{2,4}=0$?
Extension: This also made me think about swaptions. I understand that the underlying of an option is a forward (e.g., underlying of FX forward for an FX option). However, I feel a bit confused in rates space, which has to do with my question above: is the underlying of a swaption (e.g., 1y10y) the 1y10y forward rate $f_{1,10}$ or the rate on a 1y forward starting 10y swap $R_{1,10}$? Leaning towards the latter since a swaption is an option on... a swap.

"I'm leaning towards the fact that the swap rate depends on DF3
(I assume more generally on the segment between Year 2 and Year 4) but the forward rate doesn't" --Correct
"Is there a specific shape of the swap curve that would make f2,4−R2,4=0
?"- the most obvious example is a flat curve where all rates are the same
"is the underlying of a swaption (e.g., 1y10y) the 1y10y forward rate f1,10
or the rate on a 1y forward starting 10y swap R1,10
? Leaning towards the latter since a swaption is an option on... a swap."
-- Correct

Thanks for the help. Besides a flat curve, is there any other condition? Also, how should a large difference in f2,4 vs R2,4 be interpreted as? Is it a function of concavity and/or rates vol? Or am I overreaching here?

I think you are overreaching, is it not easier just to look at the mathematical formula for a zero coupon internal rate of return versus an interest rate swap rate (which are the two rates in question) and derive the conditions? In your particular case you only have 3 discount factors of relevance.

Agreed @Attack68.  You should find that in an upward sloping curve , the forward zero rates are more upward sloping than the forward swap rates, for example.

Yes, I agree that it was overreaching. Indeed, as @dm63 said, fi,j > Ri,j in an upward sloping forward curve between i+1 and j and vice versa. It is then logical that fi,j = Ri,j when the forward curve between i+1 and j is flat. I tested this with f1,3 and R1,3 and was able to find a non-flat forward curve combination that made f1,3 and R1,3 equal (f2,4=R2,4 only when f2,3=f3,4). Why is this? Is it because there's one more degree of freedom (i.e., f1,2)? Thank you both for the help so far.
